# How to center a Scroll element with Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a design that I had to center some images. I have tried UI Slider and Slick Slider to get it working, but they always break in Material CSS Modal.

Here is the screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I tried to use this CSS

//HTML

```
        <div class="scroolable">
            <img src="/assets/card4.png" alt="">
            <img src="/assets/card4.png" alt="">
            <img src="/assets/card4.png" alt="">
            <img src="/assets/card4.png" alt="">
            <img src="/assets/card4.png" alt="">
        </div>
```

//css

```
.scroolable {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

> justify-content: center;
> doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `align-items` (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) instead of `justify-content` here.

Comment: This will give ne the image on the right but not the image in the left. How do I get to show the image on the left

Answer (score 0):

As [Jeyffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9909314/jeyffrey) has stated above `align-items` is the thing you're looking for. You might want to take a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ as it might be helpful.